# weird warning while deploying a jar

Tags: deployment, jar, warnings, java

this warning comes up when I am deploying my jar file

```
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.4
```

I am trying to let it work using JRE 1.4, it is working fine I but I just want to make sure that that warning is not a problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is basically nothing, just ignore it.